# Repeating starting and finishing letter words

Tags: single-word-requests

I was able to find many words that start and end in same exact 2 or 3 letters.

For example

> **He**adac**he**
>
> **Ent**ertainm**ent**
>
> **Ing**est**ing**

I was not able to find any single word (more than 8 letters long) that had exact same **four** starting and ending letters.

Is there such a word?

Answer (score 1):

Abracadabra! With the magic of regex I found these words:

- abracadabra
- airy-fairy
- argy-bargy
- back-to-back
- beriberi
- blah-blah-blah
- blow-by-blow
- caracara
- choo-choo
- chop-chop
- chow-chow
- couscous
- cush-cush
- divi-divi
- door-to-door
- east-northeast
- east-southeast
- even-steven
- face-to-face
- four-by-four
- froufrou
- gris-gris
- half-and-half
- hand-to-hand
- head-to-head
- hush-hush
- itty-bitty
- lava-lava
- mahi-mahi
- muckamuck
- okey-dokey
- play-by-play
- pooh-pooh
- reel-to-reel
- tete-a-tete
- uricosuric
- wall-to-wall
- west-northwest
- west-southwest

Specifically the regex I used is `^(....).*\1$` and I did an [online regex dictionary search](https://www.visca.com/regexdict/).

Comment: Not to pooh-pooh this, but pretty much all of those, save "uricosuric", are "cheats" -- they are intentional repeats or are following a formula of some sort.

Comment: There is a South Indian language named "Malayalam" which can be read start-to-end, and end-to-start.